# What is the "drive level/low space" warning threshold for Windows 7?

Tags: disk-space, storage

What is the limit for the theshold for Windows 7 to trigger a "low space" warning? (here indicated by the red bar) and is it customiseable? I think it is 10% but I am not sure and can't find any definitive result/answer.

[image]

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/113754/how-to-change-the-disk-space-left-warning-in-windows-7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that it's 10%. [And apparently there is no way to change it](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/incorrect-low-space-warning-red-usage-bar-in/b42d61fd-9f5b-41d3-939a-83724aabab71).

Comment: Hmm, looks like it is 10% after all then. This was one of the things I did look at but was hoping for a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

## Free space thresholds

> [The] meter under the drive icon in My Computer uses a very simple algorithm: A drive is drawn in the warning state when it is 90% full.
>
> <sub>Source: [How full does a hard drive have to get before Explorer will start getting concerned?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/17/10092277.aspx)</sub>

According to my tests, the free space meter will consider the disk or partition almost full when the used space/total capacity ratio (rounded up to two decimal places) is higher or equal to `0.91`.

The low disk space notification is more complex:

> Windows 7 implements a timer to poll the available disk space every 10 minutes while it is running. This would be any fixed or external hard drives (USB, eSATA, 1394/FireWire). When this polling occurs, Windows 7 will pop up with a notification at the following thresholds:
>
> - Free space less than 200 MB
> - Free space less than 80 MB
> - Free space less than 50 MB
> - Free space equals zero
>
> Windows 7 does not poll Zip Drives, Floppies or any other "removable" media drives.
>
> <sub>Source: [The low disk space notification message might be delayed up to 10 minutes in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547929/en-us)</sub>

All the threshold values are hard-coded, and can't be customized.

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-low-disk-space-notification-alert-in-windows-7-vista/) says a registry modification can disable the warning:

Add a new DWORD (32bit) value to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

right click the Explorer and choose New > DWORD (32bit) Value and name this as `NoLowDiskSpaceChecks`

Double click the new DWORD and set its value to `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I'm more interested in finding out the threshold rather than disabling the warning.

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work at all. And on my machine the value already existed, I just had to flip it from False to True. Even after a restart, it had no effect and the red stayed red. I can't speak to whether it disables the "balloon" warnings, because I've never gotten those, but as for the red color shown in the OP, this doesn't fix it. Also this is the second registry mod I try that's supposed to work, but so far it looks like the people saying there's no way to change it are right.

Answer (score -3):

Create a key in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DELL\OpenManage\Client\SysInfo\HDDThresholdValue
```

Source: http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1092681342

Comment: Given the key \Software\DELL\ are you really sure this works on every PC? Secondly, this tweak is for XP and he is using Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Also, the key is related to Dell OpenManage client which is a third party program, and has nothing to do with the Windows Explorer behavior the OP asked about.

Answer (score -3):

From here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/incorrect-low-space-warning-red-usage-bar-in/b42d61fd-9f5b-41d3-939a-83724aabab71

1 Run REGEDIT as administrator

2 Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive

3 Change the values for both TileInfo and PreviewDetails keys (double click on the keys) by removing the phrase "System.PercentFull;", without the quotes.

> The TileInfo key: Before: prop:*System.PercentFull;System.Computer.DecoratedFreeSpace;System.Volume.FileSystem
>
> After: prop:*System.Computer.DecoratedFreeSpace;System.Volume.FileSystem
>
> .
>
> The PreviewDetails key: Before: prop:*System.PercentFull;System.FreeSpace;System.Capacity;System.Volume.FileSystem;*System.Volume.BitLockerProtection
>
> After: prop:*System.FreeSpace;System.Capacity;System.Volume.FileSystem;*System.Volume.BitLockerProtection

4 Open My Computer, you should be able to see the absence of the color bars. If you still see them, just restart windows explorer, or, if you don't know how to do this, just restart Windows.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.