# Is it possible to stop the color of the 'remaining disk-space bar' from changing to red when there isn't a lot of space remaining in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the disk space left warning in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/113754/how-to-change-the-disk-space-left-warning-in-windows-7)

For example, if on drive **C:**, which has total space of 465 GB, I have something like 50 GB of space remaining, the color of the bar below the drive icon in **My Computer** changes from blue to red.

I'd like to stop this from happening; I end up deleting stuff just to free some space -- even though I feel I'm not running out, as 50 GB is adequate -- so the color would change back to blue, but often later regret deleting what I then considered as unnecessary junk.