# Can I get Windows 10 to issue notification when boot drive free space is low?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I have a problem where I keep filling up drive C and Windows 10 does not notify me at all when free disk space drops below 1 gigabyte or even when it is entirely full.

Is there some windows setting I can configure so it will notify me?

Comment: There are third party apps, or you can make your own, but nothing built in for 1 GB. I do know, other versions of windows would notify you if your space was low but I don't think you could change the threshold at all as far as I know...

Comment: These are the threshold levels when you may see the pop-ups:

    Free space less than 200 MB : You are running out of disk space on drive.
    Free space less than 80 MB : You are running very low on disk space on disk
    Free space less than 50 MB : You are running very low on disk space on disk
    No free space remaining : You have run out of disk space on drive.

Comment: Source http://www.thewindowsclub.com/faq-low-disk-space-notification-or-warning-in-windows-7-how-to-disable-etc

Comment: You can't change the thresholds. See [How to change the disk space left warning in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/113754)

Comment: I don't even get a warning at 200 or 50 megs. It just goes to zero with no warning on windows 10.  Windows 7 had warnings, and so did Windows 8. But not windows 10 at least not for me.